# Creating a simple data loader for combinations in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, loops, iterator

Let's say I have the list of elements `[1, 2, 3, 4]`. I generate the list of all possible combinations of these numbers:

```
from itertools import combinations 
import random
import numpy as np

def returnCombinations(input_list, comb_size): 
    return list(combinations(arr, r)) 

def batchCombinations(input_list):
    # generate the complete list
    N = len(input_list)
    complete_list = []
    for idx in range(1, N+1):
        complete_list += list(combinations(input_list, idx))
    return complete_list

arr = [1, 2, 3, 4] 
data_list = batchCombinations(arr)
```

and I get the following list:

```
[(1,),
 (2,),
 (3,),
 (4,),
 (1, 2),
 (1, 3),
 (1, 4),
 (2, 3),
 (2, 4),
 (3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3),
 (1, 2, 4),
 (1, 3, 4),
 (2, 3, 4),
 (1, 2, 3, 4)]
```

Ok, now I want to shuffle this list and split it into a given number of batches. I do:

```
def generateBatches(lst, batch_size): 
    random.shuffle(lst)
    nr_batches = np.ceil(len(lst) / float(batch_size))
    return [lst[int(round(batch_size * i)): int(round(batch_size * (i + 1)))] for i in range(int(nr_batches)) ]

generateBatches(data_list, batch_size=2)
```

which returns:

```
[[(2, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3, 4)],
 [(4,), (1, 3)],
 [(3, 4), (1,)],
 [(1, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3)],
 [(2,), (1, 2, 4)],
 [(1, 2), (2, 3)],
 [(3,), (1, 4)],
 [(2, 4)]]
```

This is exactly what I need but it will not work for large input lists. I will have lists of 100-150,000 elements (not in any order, they can be [12, 3234, 121, 25626...] and they can't necessarily be sorted to make, say, all the numbers from 1 to 100,000. They are just labels).

How can I rewrite this code, preferably using some kind of iterator/generator, that does not build that intermediary list, nor the final one, but would somehow allow me to loop through the final one.

Ultimately I just want to run a for loop over the final list, batch-wise and parallelize over batches. How can I get to the input of that for loop?

Comment: The original list has 150,000 elements!? And you intend to iterate through its combinations of all lengthes? Batches or no batches, all in memory or lazy iterator, you will not get to the end of that loop in this lifetime. `150k choose 75k` is a number with > 45000 digits

Comment: @schwobaseggl The idea is to run with a threshold. Once my algorithm provides variation below a certain epsilon, I stop it. It will most likely not need a lot of combinations to converge, this is why I don't want to generate that ginormous list, if I'm going to need just 0.0001% of it.

Comment: I see. Generating such batches randomly and lazily seems a tough nut to crack, given tht you can't keep track of which combo you have already visited.

Comment: Yep, having the same element in two different batches will be a big problem unfortunately

Comment: The only way I see is to go about it probabilistically. Just repeatedly pick a random sample of a random size (possibly weighted by the number of combs for the sizes) and bank on repetitions being highly unlikely.

Comment: Could you please put this into a working code and I'll give it a test.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211492/discussion-between-schwobaseggl-and-qubix).